# cmake проблема со сборкой

Tags: c++, c, cmake

Собрался настроить сборку у себя на компьютере скачал последний cmake 3.9.0 с офф сайта под винду (поставил галку установить все нужные пути в PATH) и для проверки создал в папке C:/cin файл main.cpp вместе с CMakeLists.txt в нем:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

после чего прописал cmake C:/cin -G "MinGW Makefiles" в cmd

процесс пошел, но после ввода make вот что вылезло...
(без cmake до этого компилил через cmd командой gcc main.c или g++ main.cpp 
и в CodeBlocks)

[image: Собственно что происходит после make]

Может у кого-то уже была такая проблема (или кто-то может ссылку кинуть с её решением)?

Answer (score 0):

В общем полазив ещё немного по интернету и подумав решил скачать make.exe отдельно, указал в Path путь к нему, но оказалось что отсутствует libgmp-10.dll а это как раз та библиотека которая есть в MinGW, в общем прописал mingw32-make в cmd все заработало. Мне кажется ошибка была из за того что make изначально как-то к Delphi относился поэтому и возникала данная ошибка.